# Need to upgrade Go 1.2.1 to 1.3+ on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty64)

Tags: ubuntu, go, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

ENVIRONMENT
vagrant / virtualbox / ubuntu-trusty64

my Go version is 1.2.1
installed via apt-get install golang

I need and should have installed a more recent (1.3+) version (repo outdated)

Is it best to:
A - apt-get uninstall, re-install using more updated repo
B - try to upgrade existing Go to 1.3 or higher
C - ?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach I believe is to use the `godeb` tool: https://github.com/niemeyer/godeb

Answer (score 0):

I recommend uninstalling the version of Go that comes with Ubuntu (1.2.1, as you mentioned). Instead, follow the instructions on the [Go install page](http://golang.org/doc/install).

Summary:

1. Download the latest tarball for your OS. In this case, you'll want the 64-bit linux package. Currently `go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz`.
2. Open up a terminal to the directory you downloaded the tarball and type
   `sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz`
3. The package is now installed on your system, but you still need to export the binaries to your `$PATH`. So we'll [modify your environment using the Ubuntu way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh):
   `sudo echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" > /etc/profile.d/golang_bin.sh`
4. Close the terminal window, and open up a new one (so the new profile file we created gets read) then check that your installation succeeded by typing:
   `go version`

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest version of Go programming language in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install go --classic --channel stable
```

This snap provides an assembler, compiler, linker, and compiled libraries for the Go programming language. There are other channels besides stable, but the stable channel is the latest version of Go programming language. The go snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.